# Unable to update model record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, controller

I have the following form that updates my `Pack` model:

```
= form_for(@pack) do |f|
    .form-group
        = f.label :amount
        = f.text_field :amount, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control'
    = f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button right'
```

In my model, `pack.rb`, I have a uniqueness validation on `:created_on`, which seems to be preventing my update from going through. Here is my model:

```
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_on :date
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  amount     :integer
#

class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    default_scope -> { order('created_on DESC') }
    scope :today, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now)) }
    scope :week, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_week..Time.now))}
    scope :month, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now))}
    scope :year, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_year..Time.now))}

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :created_on, uniqueness: true
    validates :amount, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1 }
end
```

When I remove the uniqueness validation, the edit goes through without any problems. The `:created_on` doesn't get changed for that record, either. How do I get the record to save while also maintaining the uniqueness attribute?

Comment: Do you want to validate that no two packs can be created on the same date? If you want to validate that no user can have two packs on same date change validation to 
validates :created_on, uniqueness: true, scope: :user_id

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your phrasing. What exactly are trying to do? Are you looking to keep the uniqueness constraint but allow for multiple records with a `created_on` value of `nil` to be saved?